# How to point to a Mat in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, eigen

I've written following code to implement `LDA`. At the end of this piece code, i want to assign `eigenvaluesOpenCV` to `eigvalue` and `eigenvectorsOpenCV` to `eigvector` by `.data` pointer but even though `eigenvaluesOpenCV` and `eigenvaluesOpenCV` aren't `NULL`, `eigvector` and `eigvalue` become `NULL`. Why does this happen and how to fix this?

```
void main()
{
.
.
.
    uchar* EVectors = NULL;
    uchar* EValues = NULL;
    MYLDA(train_labels, train_data, EVectors, EValues);
.
.
.
}


void MYLDA(vector<int> gnd, Mat_<float> _data, uchar* eigvector, uchar* eigvalue)
{
    .
    .
    .
GeneralizedEigenSolver<MatrixXf> ges;

ges.compute(DPrime, WPrime);

MatrixXcf eigenvectorsInEigen = ges.eigenvectors();

VectorXcf eigenvaluesInEigen = ges.eigenvalues();

Mat eigenvectorsOpenCV(eigenvectorsInEigen.rows(), 
eigenvectorsInEigen.cols(), CV_32FC1, eigenvectorsInEigen.data());

uchar* mPtr = new uchar[eigenvectorsOpenCV.total()];

memcpy(mPtr, eigenvectorsOpenCV.data, eigenvectorsOpenCV.total());

eigvector = mPtr;

Mat eigenvaluesOpenCV(eigenvaluesInEigen.rows(), 
eigenvaluesInEigen.cols(), CV_32FC1, eigenvaluesInEigen.data());

uchar* nPtr = new uchar[eigenvaluesOpenCV.total()];

memcpy(mPtr, eigenvaluesOpenCV.data, eigenvaluesOpenCV.total());

eigvalue = nPtr;

}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `eigenvectorsOpenCV` contains `floats`, which are 32bits (i.e. 4 bytes) each. Right now you `memcpy` only 1/4 of the data.

Comment: Protip: If you're using `memcpy` in C++, you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing uchar ** or uchar &*, you're passing pointers by copy and then modifying what they point to. But that doesn't translate to the scope outside the function.